# Try block causing Stream closed IOException

Tags: java, try-catch, inputstream

My question is regarding this exception

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67)
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:142)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
com.avnet.css.servlet.PartNotificationFileServlet.doGet(PartNotificationFileServlet.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

So we recently upgraded our code for Java 7, and we had to implement a try block for a ZipFile declaration.  This seems to cause the input stream to close, where it didn't before when there was no try block.  Not sure I understand why, when it is declared before the block.  Can anyone explain or offer a solution?

```
    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    String[] tokens = uri.split("/");
    String folder = tokens[tokens.length - 2];//req.getParameter("folder");
    String filename = tokens[tokens.length - 1];req.getParameter("filename");
    Properties properties = new CSSProperties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    if(!folder.contains("_AVT")){
        //below is the new try block, when the declaration inside the parenthesis is on its own, instead of inside try, it works fine.  
        try (ZipFile docsZip = new ZipFile(new File(properties.getProperty(PCN_DIR) + File.separator + folder + File.separator + "Documents.zip"))) {
            ZipEntry entry = docsZip.getEntry(filename);
            if (entry != null)                              
                inputStream = docsZip.getInputStream(entry);
        }
    }
    else{
        String decodedFileName = URLDecoder.decode(filename, "UTF-8");
        File file = new File(properties.getProperty(PCN_DIR) + File.separator + folder + File.separator + decodedFileName);
        if(file.exists())
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
    if(inputStream != null){
        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename));
        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) //this is line 51, where the error occurs
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        inputStream.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Where is try-catch block in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current code you are using the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), so your `ZipFile docsZip` is closed as soon as the `try` is completed.

When you put the declaration of `docsZip` within the `try` it will not be closed (note that this should then be done somewhere after `out.close()`.

Comment: So if I just remove it from that line, throw it inside the try block and have an empty finally block, all will be good?

Comment: It will probably prevent the exception you are currently experiencing. Note that using an empty finally block may lead to other issues since the `docsZip` resource is never closed.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation.  Think I have it sorted out now.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behavior in [`ZipFile#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#close--):

> Closing this ZIP file will close all of the input streams previously returned by invocations of the getInputStream method.

(A Java 7 [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement calls `close` automatically at the end of the block.)